# Edges are not connected to each other

Tags: vertices, faces

I imported one of my meshes but when i tried to move one of its faces. I realized that none of the edges were connected to each other.  How do i fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, then right click and choose *Merge Vertices > By Distance*

Comment: Thank You! Wow, I was trying to select edge loop and it would not work. I figured that it was a shortcut issue but finally found this.